# Can @font-face be used on the server to specify fonts

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, font-face

I'm using `@font-face` to specify fonts to be used by the user to personalise products on a gift site.  However, whilst I have the relevant .ttf files on the server they cannot be installed.  I need to refer to/use them in a processing asp page but at present only the fonts installed on the server can be used/work.

Can the `@font-face` be used at the server?  Is there a similar command I can use? Or indeed is there another way to do it by adding some sort of script?

Comment: TTFs are NOT universal, nor do you likely have the rights to distribute them.

Answer (score 0):

To distribute a font via your website you may need a [license](http://blog.themeforest.net/general/font-licensing-for-the-web/).

If you have the rights to distribute the font on your server you can use the following style (not cross browser compatible).

```
// To download the font
@font-face {
font-family: custom_font;
src: url('custom_font.ttf');
}

// To use the font
.custom_font{
font-family: custom_font;
}
```

Or you could use an online font api such as google web [fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts#HomePlace%3ahome) to find a font alternative.

```
<html> 
<head>   
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Condiment' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
    .custom_font { font-family: 'Condiment', cursive; }
</style>
</head> 
<body> 
<h2 class="custom_font">This is my custom font</h2>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, I've managed to get this working now.  I'making sure the fonts are free to distribute.  I'll look into the Google solution.